# Is rebar required when raising window sill?

Tags: concrete, walls, masonry, rebar

I have an window opening on the side of our covered patio (concrete block/stucco).  I want to raise the sill up 24" to accommodate an outdoor kitchen counter and hide the pool pump/filter on the outside.

The new addition is 24" high and 56" wide.  I'd like to simply lay the new block on top of the existing as this would be a non structural part of the wall.  Do I need to add rebar to his new section?

Edit based on accepted answer:
The existing wall section did not have any rebar and was hollow.  I added rebar to the bottom up through the new section in every other hole and filled with concrete.

Comment: As a rule, the price of adding reinforcing steel is low, and the cost of not adding it can be high, if the structure fails under some loading, whether it be seismic, 10 gallon pot of soup dropped on the counter, people sitting or standing on the counter, etc...

Comment: Plus, rebar glued/cemented into the existing will tie old structure to new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Required, probably not

Recommended yes

Once not done it remains a questionable point compared to totally securing the 24" x 56" high new wall insert.

rebar added into the existing will tie old structure to new.